# Magento doesn't index my product

Tags: php, mysql, magento, backend

I am new to Magento programming. I added a product with my own written code. Everything goes fine. The product is created as it should be. But it is not visible at the frontend. When i open the product in the backend and save it directly it is visible at the frontend. I don't want to open it in the backend. It must be directly visible at the frontend side. And index products doesn't change anything. Wat am i doing wrong?

```
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product->setStoreId(1);
        $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
        $product->setMsrpEnabled(1);
        $product->setCategoryIds($setProductCategoryArray);
        $product->setSku($csvArray[$i][$template->artikelnummer->index]);
        $product->setName($csvArray[$i][$template->artikelnaam->index]);

        if(empty($csvArray[$i][$template->lange_omschrijving->index]) && empty($csvArray[$i][$template->korte_omschrijving->index])){
            $csvArray[$i][$template->lange_omschrijving->index] = "Geen omschrijving";
            $csvArray[$i][$template->korte_omschrijving->index] = "Geen omschrijving";
        }else if(empty($csvArray[$i][$template->lange_omschrijving->index])){
            $csvArray[$i][$template->lange_omschrijving->index] = $csvArray[$i][$template->korte_omschrijving->index];
        }else if(empty($csvArray[$i][$template->korte_omschrijving->index])){
            $csvArray[$i][$template->korte_omschrijving->index] = $csvArray[$i][$template->lange_omschrijving->index];
        }
        $product->setDescription($csvArray[$i][$template->lange_omschrijving->index]);
        $product->setShortDescription($csvArray[$i][$template->korte_omschrijving->index]);
        $product->setPrice($csvArray[$i][$template->prijs->index]);
        $product->setTypeId('simple');
        $product->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId);

        $product->setWeight(1.0);
        $product->setTaxClassId(2); // taxable goods
        $product->setVisibility(4); // catalog, search
        $product->setStatus(1); // enabled
        $product->save();
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set website of the product:

```
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID
```

or in such way:

$product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));